# "Else must be preceded by matching if statement" - unclear error

Tags: vb.net, if-statement

I have the code below. With one of the 'elseif' statements, I keep getting the error that states "'elseif' must be preceded by matching 'if' or 'elseif' statement". I've used this syntax before so I am not sure why this error has come up if anyone can provide some hints. I've looked at other examples, such as breaking up the "then" to a new line, but they don't seem to work.

It doesn't show anerror when I just put "If..then" statements, but I believe I require an "else if" statement for the decision making.

```
  Private Sub btnDeal_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnDeal.Click
    Dim suit As Double
    Dim cardval As Double
    Dim num As String
    Dim house As String


    For i = 0 To 50 Step 2 ' player 1

        suit = Math.Floor(list(i) \ 13)
        cardval = list(i) Mod 13

        If suit = 0 Then house = "Clubs"
        elseIf suit = 1 Then house = "Diamonds"
        elseIf suit = 2 Then house = "Hearts"
        else suit = 3 Then house = "Spades"
        End if

        If cardval = 0 Then num = "Ace"
        If cardval = 1 Then num = "two"
        If cardval = 2 Then num = "three"
        If cardval = 3 Then num = "four"
        If cardval = 4 Then num = "five"
        If cardval = 5 Then num = "six"
        If cardval = 6 Then num = "seven"
        If cardval = 7 Then num = "eight"
        If cardval = 8 Then num = "nine"
        If cardval = 9 Then num = "ten"
        If cardval = 10 Then num = "jack"
        If cardval = 11 Then num = "queen"
        If cardval = 12 Then num = "king"

        ListBox1.Items.Add("num" & " of " & "house")
    Next
```

End Sub

Comment: Where is mentioned c++?

Comment: You're using one-line `If`-statements. In order to add `Else` or `ElseIf` you would either have to type everything on the same line or separate it by Visual Basic's _line continuation character_, which is the underscore `_`.

Comment: Look at Select Case for this type of logic.

Comment: You could get probably get rid of the If statements and use a Select Case statement, might make it easier. One Select Case statement for the Suit and one for the cardval

Answer (score 1):

```
else suit = 3 Then house = "Spades"
```

Probably should be either:

```
elseIf suit = 3 Then house = "Spades"
```

-or-

```
else house = "Spades"
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need an elseIf. Your conditions are mutually exclusive. `suit` isn't going to change during the execution of these conditionals.

```
    If suit = 0 Then house = "Clubs"
    If suit = 1 Then house = "Diamonds"
    If suit = 2 Then house = "Hearts"
    If suit = 3 Then house = "Spades"
```

Answer (score 0):

Could use Select Case Statements instead then there would be no need of if statements

```
Select Case suit 
   Case 0
       House = "Clubs"
   Case 1
       House = "Diamonds"
   Case 2
       House = "Hearts"
   Case 3
       House = "Spades"
End Select
```

Then you can just create another Select Case Statement for card value (cardval)

```
Select Case cardval
   Case 0
       num = "Ace"
   Case 1
       num = "two"

   'and so on till all conditions are met
```